# Excel VBA with multiple search criteria and loop until all distinct results are found

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to VBA and have an extremely short deadline, so I apologize if I'm not following all forum guidelines. I'd be greatful for any help you can provide!

**Goal:**

1. Search Sheet1 for keywords (Activity:, Site Address:, Description:, Owner:, Valuation:, Sub Type: and DATE_B:)
2. Once keyword is found, offset (0,1)
3. Copy value
4. On Sheet2, label columns as such: Permit_Type, Permit_Date, Permit_Address, Permit_Desc, Owner and Permit_Val)
5. Paste copied value from Sheet1 to the appropriate columns
6. Repeat script until all keywords are no longer found Sheet1. In other words, continue throughout Sheet1.

**What works:**

1. Creates column names on Sheet2
2. Script copies and pastes the first values found

**What doesn't work:**

1. Script stops after first values are found

**Known issue:**
I originally had the values copied/pasted on the same Sheet1 in Range O2:U2.  I'm having a hard time removing this command since I just need these values to paste on Sheet2

**Data looks like this, about 100 records**
Most Keywords are in Column A, then the rest in Column E - sorry I couldn't provide a better respresentation!

```
 'Column A    Column B     Column C    Column D    Column E      Column F Column G G         
 'Activity: B13-0217       Type:  BUILD-M   Sub Type:   Porch   Status: ISSUED
 '

 'Parcel:               DATE_B: 09/13/2013  Sq Feet:    
 'Site Address: 123 Main St                     
 'Description:  Patio cover 150 sqft                        
 'Applicant:    ABC Contracting         Phone:  123-456-7890        
 'Owner:    Jane Smith          Phone:  123-456-7890        
 'Contractor:   ABC Contracting         Phone:  123-456-7890        
 'Occupancy:        Use:        Class:      Insp Area:  
 'Valuation:    $3,200.00 Fees Req:     $256.90     Fees Col:   $256.90     Bal Due:    $0.00 

 'Activity: B13-0224    Type:  BUILD-M      Sub Type:   Deck    Status: ISSUED
 'Parcel:               DATE_B: 09/27/2013  Sq Feet:    
 'Site Address: 234 South St                        
 'Description:  Install a 682 sqft deck on the east side of the building                        
 'Applicant:    BCA Contracting         Phone:  234-567-1234        
 'Owner:    Joe Smith           Phone:  234-567-1234        
 'Contractor:   BCA Contracting         Phone:  234-567-1234        
 'Occupancy:        Use:        Class:      Insp Area:  
 'Valuation:    $28,000.00 Fees Req:        $1,408.60   Fees Col:   $1,408.60   Bal Due:    $0.00
```

**Below is the script I pieced together.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

```
Sub Lafayette_Permit_arrangement_macro()

' This Macro is intended to arrange the monthly Lafayette Permit
' data so that specific data is extracted and organized in a more
' usable format for mass import.


'Permit Number
Cells.Find(What:="Activity:", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 1).Select
    Selection.Copy
Range("O2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
'Permit Type
 Cells.Find(What:="Sub Type:", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 1).Select
    Selection.Copy
 Range("P2").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
'Permit Issue Date
 Cells.Find(What:="DATE_B:", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 1).Select
    Selection.Copy
 Range("Q2").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
'Permit Address
 Cells.Find(What:="Site Address:", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 1).Select
    Selection.Copy
  Range("R2").Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
'Permit Description
 Cells.Find(What:="Description:", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 1).Select
    Selection.Copy
 Range("S2").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
'Permit Owner
 Cells.Find(What:="Owner:", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 1).Select
    Selection.Copy
 Range("T2").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
'Permit Value
 Cells.Find(What:="Valuation:", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 1).Select
    Selection.Copy
 Range("U2").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste

 Range("O2:U2").Select
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("Sheet2").Select
 Range("A2").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 Sheets("Sheet2").Select
 Range("A1").Select

 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 'Add PermitNo column to Sheet2
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Permit_No"
 Range("A1").Select
 'Add PermitType column to Sheet2
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Permit_Type"
 Range("B1").Select
 'Add PermitDate column to Sheet2
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Permit_Date"
 Range("C1").Select
 'Add PermitAdd column to Sheet2
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Permit_Address"
 Range("D1").Select
 'Add PermitDesc column to Sheet2
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Permit_Desc"
 Range("E1").Select
 'Add PermitOwner column to Sheet2
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Owner"
 Range("F1").Select
'Add PermitVal column to Sheet2
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Permit_Val"
 Range("G1").Select




End Sub
```

Comment: How is the data set out of sheet 1, you could probably use a pivot table?

Comment: You should be able to accomplish this much faster with a formula, even if you don't want to leave the formula in the cells you could use vba to enter all the formulas then convert the result of the formula to the value of the cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you should almost always avoid using select; storing values in variables or setting them directly is much faster (and cleaner at times).

Secondly, `Find` will only return the first instance of a searched parameter. You will need to utilize a combination of `FindNext` and a loop to find all instance of a parameter in a given range. Given these two facts, I would update the code with the following.

```
Dim searchResult As Range
Dim x As Integer

x = 2

' Search for "Activity" and store in Range
Set searchResult = Cells.Find(What:="Activity:", _
                     LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                     SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
                     SearchFormat:=False)

' Store the address of the first occurrence of this word
firstAddress = searchResult.Address
Do

    ' Set the value in the O column, using the row number and column number
    Cells(x, 15) = searchResult.Offset(0, 1).Value

    ' Increase the counter to go to the next row
    x = x + 1

    ' Find the next occurence of "Activity"
    Set searchResult = Cells.FindNext(searchResult)

    ' Check if a value was found and that it is not the first value found
Loop While Not searchResult Is Nothing And firstAddress <> searchResult.Address
```

After the search is complete for "Activity", for example, you would then reset x to 2 and repeat the same steps for all your other search parameters.

As @user2140261 commented, you can take further steps to make the above into a function and then either use the function within your vba code, or directly in the spreadsheet via a formula.

**UPDATE**

Given your data (which you just posted), the code I shared can be made more efficient by only searching Column A, since it seems to where you are looking for the word "Activity". In VBA, you should also try to limit your declared ranges to the source of the data (in this case, Column A, `A:A`, or even better, `A1:A5000`, or however many rows of data exist)

Therefore, instead of using `Cells.Find`, you should use range and indicate the area to be searched, e.g. `Range("A1:A5000")`

Comment: It worked perfectly!!! Thanks to all that responded your contributions are greatly appreciated!!! :)