# Searching rows for duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

I have created some code that will look at the previous row and if column D and F match then it will add the results from column G and K and delete the result.

This still leaves duplicates in my data because not all duplicates are in order (next to each other)

Could you please tell me how I can search all rows and do what I have said above **until** there are no matches at all.

```
Sub Merge_Values()
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim columnToMatch1 As Range
Dim columnToMatch2 As Range
Dim columnToSum1 As Range
Dim columnToSum2 As Range
Dim MatchChecker As Boolean

MatchChecker = False

With ActiveSheet
    Set columnToMatch1 = .Range("D:D")
    Set columnToMatch2 = .Range("F:F")
    Set columnToSum1 = .Range("G:G")
    Set columnToSum2 = .Range("K:K")

    lngRow = .Range(columnToMatch1, columnToMatch2).Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
    Do While Not lngRow = 9
        For x = columnToMatch1.Column To columnToMatch2.Column
            If .Cells(lngRow, x) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, x) Then
                MatchChecker = True
            Else
                MatchChecker = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next x
        If MatchChecker = True Then
            For y = columnToSum1.Column To columnToSum2.Column
                .Cells(lngRow - 1, y) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, y) + .Cells(lngRow, y)
            Next y
                .Rows(lngRow).Delete
        End If
        lngRow = lngRow - 1
    Loop    
 End With
End Sub
```

I assume I need something instead of **lngRow -1** but I'm not sure what I can put here to keep searching all.

OR

I may need to put it all in another 'Do while' statement but I can't make anything make sense.
Please help.

Comment: Find only delivers the first found result, you will need to utilize FindNext and loop until no results are found.. (Here)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005997/excel-vba-with-multiple-search-criteria-and-loop-until-all-distinct-results-are] is a previously answered question that may help you get on your way to doing what you need. I'm not by my computer right now, but if you need additional help let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using a dictionary object:

```
Sub Merge_Values()

Const START_ROW As Long = 10

Dim firstRw As Long
Dim dict As Object, rngDelete As Range
Dim arrMatchCols, arrSumCols, i As Long
Dim rw As Range, k As String, tmp, noValue as Boolean, sep As String

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    arrMatchCols = Array(4, 5, 6)       'composite key
    arrSumCols = Array(7, 8, 9, 10, 11) 'columns to sum

    With ActiveSheet

        Set rw = .Rows(START_ROW)

        Do
            k = ""
            noValue = True
            sep = ""
            For i = LBound(arrMatchCols) To UBound(arrMatchCols)
                tmp = rw.Cells(arrMatchCols(i)).Value
                If Len(tmp) > 0 Then noValue = False
                k = k & sep & tmp
                sep = vbNull
            Next i
            If noValue Then Exit Do 'no more rows - exit loop

            If dict.exists(k) Then 'not first time for this combination...
                firstRw = dict(k) 'get first row

                'loop though "sum" columns and add values to first row
                For i = LBound(arrSumCols) To UBound(arrSumCols)
                    With .Rows(firstRw).Cells(arrSumCols(i))
                        .Value = .Value + rw.Cells(arrSumCols(i)).Value
                    End With
                Next i

                'build range to delete
                If rngDelete Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngDelete = rw
                Else
                    Set rngDelete = Application.Union(rngDelete, rw)
                End If
            Else
                dict(k) = rw.Row 'first time for this key: save row value
            End If

            Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0) 'next row
        Loop

    End With

    'delete duplicates if found
    If Not rngDelete Is Nothing Then rngDelete.Delete

End Sub
```